# No CSS/formatting on wordpress blog from external computers

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm trying to set up a wordpress blog hosted from my computer using [this tutorial](http://wpgarage.com/good-blogging-practice/how-to-set-up-wordpress-on-a-wampserver/). When I visit the site on the computer it's hosted on, via localhost or the IP of the computer, the site looks fine, but when I visit it from another computer it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM1Vk.png).

Comment: Its probably not able to successfully request the stylesheet and other image resources. If you have Chrome you can quickly check what it is not able to retrieve via Tools | Developer Tools. I believe if it cannot locate a resource like a .js, or css file it will display that error

Answer (score 3):

All Wordpress resources (stylesheets and images at least) use Wordpress' URL configuration. You can find it as the 3rd option down in the General Configuration page of your Admin. This is due to the way that themes are to be programmed and create the header of the blog using the [`bloginfo` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) that uses those configuration values to generate the rest of them

What is probably happening is that such URL is using either localhost or 127.0.0.1. If that is the case, when accessing the blog from your own PC it would show fine as both do resolve to the local machine. If you access it from an external PC, they would not resolve to the PC that is serving Wordpress but also to the local PC - which is not able to provide them.

Comment: Yeah I think it's the second thing you said. What do I do to fix it, since it does in fact serve some words of the site, just not everything?

Comment: your best bet is to change that setting to use the IP of the machine (the one you use to access the blog from another PC

Comment: This answer really saved me a lot of time! Even though it's somehow sad, that this did not change until 2017.