# Theme Not Working When Visited from Separate Computer on New Wordpress Blog

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wamp

I am using WAMP with a new WordPress blog. I am hosting this on a local computer. Upon my arrival at this URL from a separate computer a lack of CSS appearance becomes evident. To clarify myself further, when I view this site on another computational device designed to compute the CSS that ought to load does not perform its designated task. Perhaps the scripts are not performing their tasks? PHP scripts that WordPress uses may have errors impairing the overall performance from an external device. My English, please excuse, and have my deepest respect comrades.

Comment: Is this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875087/no-css-formatting-on-wordpress-blog-from-external-computers

Comment: What exactly do you expect from everyone here. Without code samples or a URL, we're just guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you installed your blog with an url like `http://localhost/blog`

In the WordPress database the url is used to find the link for CSS, theme files, etc...

Accessing from another computer with your ip address (let's say that is 192.168.1.5) will break the css, because, if you look at the code of your wordpress page you'll see links pointing to localhost, that has no meaning for the other machine (or better, for the other machine means "myself", so it will look for css on its filesystem and not on your remote pc).

Sorry for the bad english. :P